# Can't connect to Postgres db remotely when deployed on GCP

Tags: django, postgresql, google-cloud-platform

So I'm not sure what code to include that might help so let me know and I can add it. I have a Django web app that I'm deploying on Google Cloud Platform. The app has you search a zip code, then call the Yelp API, adds what it returned to a DB, then pulls from the DB to display in the template. This works perfectly when running locally with a SQLite DB. I've created a Postgres DB and that seems to be working when running locally through cloud_sql_proxy as well.

The problem is when deployed it will only search what is already in the DB but cannot add to it. If you search for a zip code that's not already in the DB it returns 500 server error. You can try for yourself [HERE](https://restroom-rater-281118.uc.r.appspot.com/). Zip codes 78626 and 55075 work because that's what i tested it with when running locally. if I run locally and do another zip, then deploy, that zip will suddenly work.

Please let me know if there's anything i can provide for more context.

**EDIT**: When I deploy and run in DEBUG mode, it returns a KeyError when calling the Yelp API.

**yelp_api.py**

```
YELP_API_KEY = os.environ.get('YELP_API_KEY')

def get_name(location):
    """ makes call to Yelp API and returns list of establishments within the given zip code """
    
    url = 'https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search'
    params = {
        'location': f'{location}',
        'limit': 50
    }
    
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {YELP_API_KEY}'}

    try:
        response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers).json()
        for venue in response['businesses']:

etc. etc.
```

Particularly at the `for venue in response['businesses']` line. It says `Exception Value: 'businesses'`. Not sure if that means it's not calling the API to begin with or it's just unable to parse the response for some reason. Again, all of this works when running locally.

Comment: Okay, so I'm clear... If the zip code doesn't exist in the DB yet, it calls out to the Yelp API, and writes the results into the DB (essentially cacheing the results from Yelp) so subsequent queries just hit the Cloud SQL db (cache)? From the URL for trying it out, it looks like you're using AppEngine for deploying the app, yes? Did you go through these docs to be sure your AppEngine can see your Cloud SQL instance: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard ?

Comment: And I just realized, probably yes since you can read from the DB...so it's a write problem. 500 means the code is crashing somewhere. Are you catching all exceptions? At this point, I usually go to lots of print statements all over and see where it's crashing.

Comment: I edited the question to include where exactly the error is being thrown. I tried following the app engine documentation you provided but was unable to get it working.

Comment: Key exception means the key doesn't exist in the response. Try printing out the whole response and see what you have in there.

Comment: I was able to get it working while deployed when I hard coded my yelp api key. I'm assuming this means it's not finding the environment variable I had set when deployed? If I set an environment variable on my local machine, does that transfer when deploying or do I have to set it again somewhere else? And thanks so much for the help so far!

Comment: OKAY I figured it out! I had never set the environment variable in my app.yaml

Comment: Nice! There ya go. :) I would post an answer to your own question with the answer of what it was and accept your own answer so that it "closes" the question out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had set my Yelp API key as an environment variable on my local machine but not in my app.yaml which is why it was working locally but not when deployed.